# How much time does opencv haar training take?

Tags: opencv

i am trying to train a haar cascade of 900 positive images and 1700 negative images. how much time does it take to complete the training. also, how many stages, minhitrate and maxfalsealarm rate should be used for the above mentioned samples.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on CPU clock rate, number of stages specified, boosting type (DAB is the fastest) and other things.

On my 4 Gb DDR3, 2.5 Hgz, Win-64 machine to train 18 stages with 1k pos, 2k neg, Real Ada Boosting, took approximately 6-8 hours.

I use default `minhitrate` and `maxfalsealarm` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to EC2 helped my training times a lot. Very CPU-intensive.